Fastest way to approximate CDF in Mathematica
I need a very fast way to approximate the CDF of HypergeometricDistribution in Mathematica.
I need to evaluate it for very large numbers. For example
Nx = 10^7; n = 1/10 Nx; x = 1/100 n; k = Round [1.1 Nx x/n]
dist = HypergeometricDistribution[n, k , Nx];

N[CDF[dist, x], 5] // AbsoluteTiming


(*{10.2307, 6.5780*10^-25}*)


The output can be approximated very quickly by,
NProbability[9/10 x <= var <= x, 
  var \[Distributed] dist] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.13286, 6.57802*10^-25}*)


Approximating the CDF is a major bottleneck in my program and becomes more of an issue for even larger numbers.
Is there anything better than this?
EDIT
The way such a function would fit into my code is as follows.
While[cumulativeApprox[k]>p,expr]


where k is the number of successes in the total population for fixed Nx,n,x (see above) and p is also a fixed quantity.

Does your code deal with different Hypergeometric distributions or the same one over and over again?

Different. The parameter k changes.

You should use arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision. It is slower; however, it is much safer. NProbability[9/10 x <= var <= x, var \[Distributed] dist, WorkingPrecision -> 15] // AbsoluteTiming

How is this question different from your previous question on the Hypergeometric distribution?

This is rather a math than Mathematica question. See Wiki as a first reading. BTW, n = 1/10 Nx; x = 1/100 n; k = Round [1.1 Nx x/n]; as=Asymptotic[CDF[HypergeometricDistribution[n, k , Nx], x],Nx->Infinity] performs several lines and then as/.Nx->10^7 gives 0..

Your numbers are very large and the result very small.
tr = Trace[CDF[dist, x]]; 

is showing a Rational of very large integers
Log[N@Through[{Numerator, Denominator}[tr[[-1, 1]]]]] 

{480579.464043239822212, 480635.144937519555372}
So use one of the approximations to such a monster of fractions of binomial coefficients, binomial, Poisson or normal Approximate hypergeometric distribution for large samples
if the fact that drawing with or without discarding the drawn balls makes no difference.
